# Objective-C freezed GUI also with queue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I'm trying to understand queue in iOS; with this code

```
dispatch_queue_t coda_thread=dispatch_queue_create("coda_thread",NULL);

//UIPROGRESS VIEW
for(i=0;i<=10;i=i+1)
{    
dispatch_async(coda_thread,
    ^{
        NSLog(@"CODA_THREAD");
        NSLog(@"attendo..");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            NSLog(@"MAIN THREAD");
            NSLog(@"aggiorno barra.."); 
            [self.upv setProgress:i/10 animated:YES];

        });
    });

}
```

I expected no freeze in GUI because sleep is in coda_thread (and not in main queue where is updated the GUI) queue while setProgress in main queue.. Instead I have freeze in my GUI..why this?

Comment: please post the proper code. You are missing a bracket and a semicolon

Comment: Look into [`dispatch_after()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after).

Comment: When it freezes, pause the app in the debugger and look at what's happening on the main thread at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a dispatch queue is not a new thread. You have no guarantee that the dispatch queue is actually using a different thread. Combining GCD API with thread API just won't work.

Comment: O_O so.. you're telling me that my new queue could run in main thread??How can avoid it?

Comment: i ckecked...there are 2 different thread and the code is executed correnctly in two different queue..but it freezes also when it is executing in different thread